# custom seekbar not showing

Tags: android, xml, seekbar

I created a custom seekbar. 
It looks normal on the Android emulator, but only the thumb is visible on the actual device. 
If you subtract the android:progressDrawable or android:thumb attributes from the properties of the seekbar in the xml file, the thumb or progressbar will look normal. 
The seekbar is not visible properly when you apply two properties at the same time.

here is source.

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="speakeragent.com.myapplication.MainActivity">

<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/seekBar1"
    android:layout_width="368dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/seekbar_seekbar1"
    android:thumb="@drawable/seekbar_thumb1"
    android:thumbOffset="0dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

seekbar_seekbar1.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@android:id/background">
    <shape android:shape="line">
        <stroke android:width="6dp" android:color="#D5D5D5" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress">
    <clip>
        <shape android:shape="line">
            <stroke android:width="6dp" android:color="#B2CCFF"/>
        </shape>
    </clip>
</item>

<item android:id="@android:id/progress">
    <clip>
        <shape android:shape="line">
            <stroke android:width="6dp" android:color="#6799FF"/>
        </shape>
    </clip>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

seekbar_thumb1.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<solid android:color="#B2CCFF"></solid>
<stroke android:width="2dp"
    android:color="#B2CCFF"/>
<size
    android:width="6dp"
    android:height="6dp"/>
</shape>
```